# What's the effect of `override` in concrete class extending abstract class?

Tags: scala, overriding, abstract

In Scala, what's the difference between :

```
abstract class Car { def drive(distance: Integer) : Unit  }
class BMW extends Car { def drive(distance: Integer) = println("I'm driving") }
```

and :

```
abstract class Car { def drive(distance: Integer) : Unit  }
class BMW extends Car { override def drive(distance: Integer) = println("I'm driving") }
```

Specifically, what's the exact effect of the `override` keyword?

Comment: I require my programmers to use `override` *only* when it actually is overriding an inherited implementation.

Comment: @RandallSchulz why ? can you explain ?

Comment: There are cases where you can use the `override` keyword even though nothing is being overridden. I find that misleading and require it not be done in our code base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case none, because you are not providing a concrete implementation of the `drive` method in `abstract class Car`.

When defined like this:

```
def drive(distance: Integer) : Unit
```

The methods behave like Java interfaces. Specifically, any concrete implementers of the abstract class must define implementation for those methods.

You will even get an error otherwise. Something like: `class BMW must be abstract`. The `override` keyword is useless in your case, but if the method did have implementation:

```
class BMW extends Car {def drive(distance: Integer) = println("blabla"); }
```

Now this will require overriding in extending classes:

```
class BMWX5 extends BMW { def drive(distance: Integer) = println("x5"); } // won't work
class BMWX5 extends BMW { override def drive(distance: Integer) = println("x5"); }// will compile
```

Answer (score 4):

`override` is useful in case when you can create a new method instead of overriding existing method without knowing:

```
abstract class Car { def drive(distance: Integer) : Unit  }
```

without `override`:

```
abstract class BMW extends Car { def drive(distance: Int) = println("I'm driving") }
```

with `override`:

```
scala> abstract class BMW extends Car { override def drive(distance: Int) = println("I'm driving") }
<console>:8: error: method drive overrides nothing.
Note: the super classes of class BMW contain the following, non final members named drive:
def drive(distance: Integer): Unit
       abstract class BMW extends Car { override def drive(distance: Int) = println("I'm driving") }
                                                     ^
```

In case of `abstract` method `override` keyword is not so useful, but it could be a good practice to `override` even abstract methods just in case. It depends on conventions in project.

`override` keyword for abstract methods makes it clear to readers that this method is defined in parent class/trait without looking to the parent class declaration.